# Specify DataContext in code

Tags: wpf, xaml, datacontext

I have a simple View that I want to bind to my ViewModel. I am currently using the Source= format for the data binding, but would like to convert that into specifying the DataContext in code.

This is what I have and it is working ...

XAML:

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Button Content="Click">
        <local:EventToCommand.Collection>
            <local:EventToCommandCollection>
                <local:EventToCommand Event="Click" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=ClickCommand, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
                <local:EventToCommand Event="GotFocus" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=GotFocusCommand}" />
            </local:EventToCommandCollection>
        </local:EventToCommand.Collection>
    </Button>
</Window>
```

ViewModel Code:

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public Command ClickCommand { get; set; }
    public Command GotFocusCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new Command((obj) => { Execute(obj); return null; });
        GotFocusCommand = new Command((obj) => { Execute(obj); return null; });
    }

    void Execute(object param)
    {
        if (param != null)
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(param.ToString());
        else
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Execute");
    }
}
```

Now all I want to do is this in my Window's code behind :

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

and remove the Window.Resources section in XAML, but I can not figure out how I should change my Binding strings accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "you are not sure"? Dont you have access to the XAML code? Cant you remove the `Source={StaticResource ViewModel}` section from every binding epression you have used on the XAML? If you do that the data will be picked up from the `DataContext` itself.

Comment: Please see my comment below ...

Comment: @Olivger, according to http://adammills.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/eventtocommand-action-mvvm-glue/ what @Rachel said should work. Please see your visual studio's `Output` window and check if you receive any binding errors
...

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContext` is the default `Source`, so this should work:

```
<local:EventToCommand Event="GotFocus" Command="{Binding GotFocusCommand}" />
```

Comment: That'll use the DataContext of the parent element, in this case a button. Which likely is going to work. But some elements, like UserControls, don't inherit the DataContext from the parent visual, and thus you would have to set it manually.

Comment: My EventToCommandCollection is defined as EventToCommandCollection : List<EventToCommand> and it seems like the DataContext propagation from the Window stops there and so never "reaches" the specified entries. Changing the strings as suggested does not work. Why does the DataContext stop there ?

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen, you are seriously mistaken. `DataContext` is always inherited as long as the element belongs to the visual tree may it be user control or whatever. Things that do not inherit data context are ContextMenus, Popups, DataGridColumns. We have to manually "attach" them to the visual tree for them to inherit the data context.

Comment: Nay, UserControls always caused issues for alarm. Though this specific issue might be Silverlight only. Hard to remember.

Comment: I do receive lots of System.Data.Warning errors in my Output window ! I also came across other references stating that I should base my class on FrameworkElement for the DataContext to propagate to it also. The only problem is that if I inherit from FrameWorkElement I can not add my class as the content for all controls as you can not set the content more than once. A bit of a catch 22, I am going to investigate adding it to the Visual Tree ...